# JS jumping code lines and loosing variable references

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a couple of really weird issues with JS, I don't know if they are related but they both look like coming from a same code execution strangeness:

This is the first one, which almost got me mad since I could't find any explanation for why it was happening and had to totally rewrite the code to make this issue disappear, inside an express app:

```
exports.someMiddleware(req, res) {
  var something = req.somethingFromPastMiddleware
  something = doSomeComputation(something) //all synchronous

  console.log(something, something.someProp) //everything ok
  if(something.someProp) {
    //here is where I must throw the error
    console.log(something, something.someProp) //undefined; error, cannot read someProp of undefined (wtf?????)
    something.otherProp = doSomeOtherComputation(something) //all synchronous
  }
  console.log(something, something.someProp) //everything ok
  res.status(200).json(something) //I get the response, without something.otherProp
}
```

the only times I got something.otherProp in the response was when I purposely created an error inside the if(something.someProp) code block, like referencing an undeclared variable and catching catching it

and now the second one, inside a react web app we have a promise chain:

```
api.dataConfirm(
  this.refs.code.value()
).then(() => {
  data.refresh();
).then(() => {
  this.returnToApp();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

this code runs fine everywhere, except for the iOS webview on iOS 9.x running on an actual iPhone (iPods ok, iPads ok, emulator ok)
on the physical iPhone data.refresh() gets called and returns the promise but don't actually do anything, also here making JS to throw an error on purpose, catching it and then going further makes the code run in the normal way

```
refresh() {
  return api.dataStatus()
    .then(res => {
      //here is where I must throw the error
      this.cache(res.body.data);
    });
}
```

I cannot really tell what's going on, maybe some code execution optimization that in some particular cases does this stuff and interrupting execution with an error and then resuming it makes things work fine... guesses?

PS: Another thing that make it work is doing some random coding before the lines that get jumped, like creating vars, summing numbers, etc... but the error thing it's the only one that works for sure

Comment: Might want to post doSomeComputation...  It does not look like it is synchronous...

Comment: @Gary
`function (something, param1, param2) {
var _a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))

  if(_a.b) {
    if(param1) {
      _a.b.c = (_.findWhere(_a.b.d, param1)) ? true : false
    }
    if(_a.b.e) {
      delete _a.b.e.f1
      delete _a.b.e.f2
      delete _a.b.e.f3
      delete _a.b.e.f4
    }
    delete _a.b.g
    delete _a.b.d
  }

  if(param2){
    _a.z1 = param2.a
    _a.z2 = param2.b
    _a.z3 = param2.c
    delete _a.j
  }
  return _a
}`
it's just some reformatting based on some params, so I'm pretty confident it is synchronous =/